# Making draggable button in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton, uitouch

I'm trying to move to UIImageViews using UITouch.
I've 2 imageViews say image1 and image2. I've these declared in .h file as UIIMageView *image1; UIImageView *image2;

NOw in the touchesBegan method, to drag an imageView, i used if condition as follows

```
 if([touch view] = image1){
    image1.center = location;
 } 
 else if([touch view] = image2){
    image2.center = location;
 }
```

where location is CGPoint.

With this code when i build n run the program, both the images overlap on each other  move together.
I want to move them individually.

Some help or any bug please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` statements **set** `[touch view]` using `=`. If you wish to test for equality, then you must use `isEqual:` which is the `NSObject` way of saying `==`:

```
 if([[touch view] isEqual:image1]){
    image1.center = location;
 } 
 else if([[touch view] isEqual:image2]){
    image2.center = location;
 }
```

Comment: Awww... My fault i'm suppose to test the equality. 
Made correction, now working fine.. :)
thank you for your help.